# Meaning of "So, too, may be the fate of his seed"

Tags: meaning, inversion

The Da Vinci Code (movie, 2006) has this:

> Once the sarcophagus is destroyed, DNA testing will be impossible. There is no way to prove a living bloodline. But if you had to... would you do as councils have done before us? Christ...Christ sacrificed his life for the betterment of humanity. So, too, may be the fate of his seed.

([Transcript](https://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?t=38944))

What does the last sentence mean?

---

@KateBunting said it means:

> "It may also be the fate of his descendants [to sacrifice their lives for the betterment of humanity]."

I understand that something like that must be the intended meaning. What I still don't understand is how you can use the construction "So, too, may be the fate of his seed" to mean something like that.

So this question is really about the syntax of the sentence and whether it's well-formed or not to convey such a meaning.

Comment: In this context "seed" = progeny/offspring

Comment: @BillyKerr - I'm glad you made that clear! Dan Brown seems to have the same problem that Mark Twain accused James Fenimore Cooper of having, namely an unerring tendency to choose exactly the wrong word. In this case an rather unfortunate picture had arisen in my mind's eye.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - maybe it's deliberate innuendo.  Could be a line from a Carry On film. LOL.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey eh?  The Lain word "semen" ***means*** seed.  What do seeds create?  That's right: offspring.  (Since you don't know what the literal definition "semen" is, you'll be downright shocked to learn what *vagina* means in Latin.)

Answer (score 15):

In Biblical language *seed* (meaning 'semen') was often used to mean 'descendants', particularly with reference to Abraham.

> As He promised to our forefathers, Abraham and his seed for ever (Magnificat).

I gather that *The Da Vinci Code* speculates about the possibility of Jesus having left descendants. So, the sentence means "It may also be the fate of his descendants [to sacrifice their lives for the betterment of humanity]."

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148158/discussion-on-answer-by-kate-bunting-meaning-of-so-too-may-be-the-fate-of-his); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

The translation of the King James Version (KJV) Bible, originally published in 1611, had a great impact on the English language, as those who have studied into this well know--including the introduction of new vocabulary into the English language, and new uses for that which previously existed.

To understand the meaning of the word "seed" in the sentence in question requires a modicum of understanding as to how this word was used in the Biblical text.

While the word "seed" is used in the KJV, dating back to its translation from Hebrew "זֶ֔רַע" (zera), to refer to descendants, its meaning is broader than this.  The same Hebrew word is used for both plants and for people, which is why the English translation of "seed," as opposed to something like "semen," is accurate.  According to [etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/word/seed), as much as three centuries prior to the KJV translation, usage of "seed" to apply to human progeny already existed in English, though today this usage is considered archaic.

The Dictionary.app on my Mac has the following as its second sense of meaning under "seed":

> 2 a man's semen. 
> • *archaic* (chiefly in biblical use) a person's
> offspring or descendants.

However, this reflects what the word has come to mean *today*, not what it used to mean, nor its application in the Hebrew original, nor as continued in the Greek text of the Bible.

In [Webster's 1828 Dictionary](https://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/seed), the nominal (noun) meaning of "seed" is as follows:

> SEED, *noun*
>
> 1. The substance, animal or vegetable, which nature prepares for the reproduction and conservation of the species. The seeds of plants are
>    a deciduous part, containing the rudiments of a new vegetable. In some
>    cases, the seeds constitute the fruit or valuable part of plants, as in
>    the case of wheat and other esculent grain; sometimes the seeds are
>    inclosed in fruit, as in apples and melons. When applied to animal
>    matter, it has no plural.
> 2. That from which any thing springs; first principle; original; as the seeds of virtue or vice.
> 3. Principle of production.
>
> *Praise of great acts he scatters as a seed. Waller.*
>
> 4. Progeny; offspring; children; descendants; as the seed of Abraham; the seed of David. In this sense, the word is applied to one person,
>    or to any number collectively, and admits of the plural form; but
>    rarely used in the plural.
> 5. Race; generation; birth.
>
> *Of mortal seed they were not held. Waller.*

Notice especially the usage applied to "seed" by the second definition above.  That usage follows more closely to the manner in which the word "seed" is used in the Bible.

In the Bible, while "seed" can mean one's descendants in a physical sense, it also encompasses a spiritual sense of progeny.  In the spiritual application, there are two "seeds" presented throughout the Bible: the "seed" of the serpent (who tempted Eve to sin), and the "seed" of Christ.  In each of these usages, the "seed" refers to *followers*, and not to physical progeny.  This is made clear in Jesus' explanation of the well-known "Parable of the Sower":

> But **he that received seed into the good ground is he that heareth
> the word, and understandeth it**; which also beareth fruit, and
> bringeth forth, some an hundredfold, some sixty, some thirty. (Matthew
> 13:23, KJV)

If one can be called a "seed" for one's understanding (belief), it is clear that this is not limited to one's physical genetics.

This leads to an explanation of what is meant in those last two sentences of the quote:

> Christ sacrificed his life for the betterment of humanity. So, too,
> may be the fate of his seed.

Christ died as a martyr for the principles he espoused and taught, or, as the sentence states: "for the betterment of humanity."  If "his seed" may suffer the same "fate," this implies that those who follow Christ and do as he did, may also end up sacrificing their lives for their cause.

Comment: I don't quite understand why both @KateBunting and you are focusing on the word 'seed'. Please note that the question is not about the meaning of the word but about the construction of "So + modal + be + subject" when there's no presence of the verb "be" in the prior sentence.

Comment: @listeneva you say the question is about the **syntax** and not about the meaning of the phrase, so why is the verb "meaning" in the question title? `Meaning of "So, too, may be the fate of his seed"` People/users may skim the question body because they think they already know where the focus lies. And you also repeat the question in the body as well `What does the last sentence mean?`

Comment: @listeneva you edited your question two hours ago, it is very likely that Biblasia was already composing their answer *before* the edit was made.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Correctly parsing the syntax is necessary to truly understand the meaning, so I don't know what you're talking about. Note that I've never asked for the meaning of the word 'seed'. I've only asked about the meaning of the entire sentence, for which you'd need to know the syntax cold.

Comment: But users will think the stumbling block of your incomprehension is the term "seed" itself. You asked for the meaning of the sentence, that is true, but you didn't *clarify*, until now, what was *really* confusing you.  Reading the comments below Kate Bunting's answer it's clear what and why you posted the question, so you had time to edit, add the details and clarify the question. Why didn't you? Adding bold to the necessary part would have helped e.g. ***So, too, may be*** *the fate of his seed*. Kate's answer explains the meaning of this section too.

Comment: @listeneva The word "so" in "So, too, may be..." appears to be a colloquial substitute for the word "such," which would act as a determiner or pronoun, whose antecedent was found in the prior sentence. Many English speakers conflate the two words, and parallel usages abound. Consider "so that" and "such that" as one example. ([HERE](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so) we see "so" can act as a pronoun.) As the subject of this independent sentence, it needn't conform to the pattern of the prior sentence, i.e. there is no need for the verb "be" to have been used in the prior sentence.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you for understanding...and, yes, after seeing these comments, I saw the new version of the question for the first time.  I had indeed been answering based on the pre-edit version.

Comment: @Biblasia Could you provide me with some attested examples of "so" being used as a pronoun and as the subject of an independent sentence? I can't think of any.

Comment: @listeneva The link I shared above had an example, one which follows a common sentence structure with using "so":  _"if you have to file a claim, do so as soon as possible."_  The use of "so" here is a pronoun whose antecedent is the idea "file a claim."  A noun is a person, place, thing, event, or idea, and "so" here functions much like "it" to encompass an idea.  In fact, "so" could be replaced by "it" in the sentence with no change in grammatical form or meaning.

Comment: @Biblasia But that "so" isn't the subject of a sentence. I'd like you to find me some attested examples of "so" being used as the subject (as you claim it is in the OP).

Comment: @listeneva Actually, I may have misspoken regarding "so" being the subject. As I look at it more carefully, in the example sentence from your OP, it appears to be the object--which is as it is usually used as a pronoun. You could flip the sentence around to say: "The fate of his seed may be so, too." This shows the subject is "the fate of his seed." However, "so" still has the same antecedent, from the previous sentence, with this rearrangement; the same antecedent I earlier identified. I can't think of a good example where "so" would act as the subject pronoun, but many where it is an object.

Comment: @Biblasia First, the verb "be" is intransitive, so I don't understand how "so" could be an object. Second, why do you think the inversion of "may be" and the subject "he fate of his seed" occurred here? The inversion starting with "so" that I know of is as in: "A: She's interested in math. B: So am I." Here, the "am" is possible only when you have the verb "be" (is) in the prior sentence. You can't say "A: She loves math. B: So am I." or  "A: She loves math. B: So may be those math teachers."

Comment: @listeneva A subject complement can be a noun or an adjective, and a noun can be replaced by a pronoun.  Yes, verbs of being are linking verbs, and are not considered transitive verbs.  They have complements.

Comment: @Biblasia Is there any reason you don't respond to my second question in the previous comment?